# Access localStorage of a url opened in another tab using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, browser-extension

I have a chrome extension which is accessible from a particular website url. I need to get the local storage of an iframe available in this website which is cross-origin domain, which is not possible. So as a work around I want to open the iframe url as a new tab, unfocused and access the localStorage of that tab from the  chrome extension. How can I get the localStorage of the new opened tab

Comment: You don't. Local storage is sandboxed for all domains for security reasons. Your extension sounds highly suspicious.

Comment: You can. Simply declare a content script for that iframe's URL and access the storage there, then send a message to your extension.